# How to create Settings for Switching ON and OFF of 'keep_screen_ON'

Tags: java, android, xml

I have been struggling to create a CheckBox Switch for FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON that can switch ON/OFF the screen display. I have managed to create it but it only works for one activity. I want to place the button maybe in the MainActivity where it will be easier for a user to quickly decide to either keep the screen ON/OFF. I want it to be one and only control switch for the entire activities in the app.
Please any help will be much appreciated.

This is what i did that doesn't work as a control settings in all activities.

**This is the XML**

```
<RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_bg2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30sp">



    <Switch
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"

       android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/ScreenController"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Keeps Screen OFF"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_bg2"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ScreenController"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:id="@+id/StatusText"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**This is the Java code**

```
MySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                         boolean isChecked) {

                if(isChecked){

                    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
                    String currentText = MySwitch.getText().toString();
                    MyText.setText(currentText.equals("Screen Light Stays ON") ? "Screen Light Stays OFF" : "Screen Light Stays ON");
                    MyText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFEB3B"));

                }else{

                    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

                    String currentText = MySwitch.getText().toString();
                    MyText.setText(currentText.equals("Screen Light Stays OFF") ? "Screen Light Stays ON" : "Screen Light Stays OFF");
                    MyText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));


                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save your variable in shared preference then have an activity that checks the variable and sets the flag.
you will then just extend this activity in all your activities.

```
 public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String shared_prefs_name="MY_prefs_name";


     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(screen_on()){

            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);


        }else{

            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);



        }

    }
   public void set_screen_on( boolean screen_on) {


        SharedPreferences.Editor saver = getSharedPreferences(shared_prefs_name, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

        saver.putBoolean("screen_on", screen_on);
        saver.commit();
        if(screen_on)
        {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        }else{

            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        }

    }

    public boolean screen_on() {



        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(shared_prefs_name, MODE_PRIVATE);
        return prefs.getBoolean("screen_on", false);


    }
}
```

So you can use it in you activity like so .

```
public class Main3Activity extends Main2Activity {

    Switch MySwitch;
    TextView MyText;
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        MySwitch=(Switch)findViewById(R.id.ScreenController);
         MyText=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.StatusText);
        MySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                         boolean isChecked) {

                set_screen_on(isChecked);
                if(isChecked){


                    String currentText = MySwitch.getText().toString();
                    MyText.setText(currentText.equals("Screen Light Stays ON") ? "Screen Light Stays OFF" : "Screen Light Stays ON");
                    MyText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFEB3B"));

                }else{



                    String currentText = MySwitch.getText().toString();
                    MyText.setText(currentText.equals("Screen Light Stays OFF") ? "Screen Light Stays ON" : "Screen Light Stays OFF");
                    MyText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));


                }
            }
        });

        if(screen_on())
        {

            String currentText = MySwitch.getText().toString();
            MyText.setText(currentText.equals("Screen Light Stays ON") ? "Screen Light Stays OFF" : "Screen Light Stays ON");
            MyText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFEB3B"));
        }else{
            String currentText = MySwitch.getText().toString();
            MyText.setText(currentText.equals("Screen Light Stays OFF") ? "Screen Light Stays ON" : "Screen Light Stays OFF");
            MyText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }

        }
    }
```

Main thing is to extend Main2Activity to get accees to the boolean `screen_on()` and to set with `set_screen_on(boolean);`

Comment: Wonderful tutorial and straight to the point. There is a problem, I discovered that if the status of the switch box is ON and i close the App. If i launch the app again the text status will be correct but the box will keep to the left but internally the program is ON. Unless it is retrieved by tapping twice to adjust the position. How do correct it in the SharedPreference

Comment: I have been trying to fix it on my own but the switchbox does not keep to physical position even though it ON as set by sharedPreference internally

Comment: just put MySwitch.setChecked(screen_on()); inside the oncreate

Comment: Wonderful i should have taught of that. I also set this MyText.setText("Screen Light Stays OFF"); in the oncreate. Worked like charm!!!!! You are indeed a program Wizard of the first order.THANK YOU SIR  for your time and assistance.